# Not able to show header after 2 scroll-up counts. Currently shows on 1 scroll up count

Tags: javascript, css

Currently, the header hides when scrolling down and shows when scrolling up once. I would like the header to show only when scrolling up twice or more times. I have tried changing the condition to (scrollUp_Count > 12) and  (scrollUp_Count > 12) but to no avail.

```js
const body = document.body
let lastScroll = 0;
let scrollUp_Count = 0;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset

    
    //top of the page
    if (currentScroll <= 0 ) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-up")
        scrollUp_Count = 0
    }

    // Scrolling down
    if (currentScroll > lastScroll && !body.classList.contains("scroll-down")) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-up")
        body.classList.add("scroll-down")
        scrollUp_Count = 0

    }
    // Scrolling up
    if (currentScroll < lastScroll && body.classList.contains("scroll-down")) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-down")
        scrollUp_Count++
        // body.classList.add("scroll-up")
    
        if (scrollUp_Count >= 2) {
            body.classList.add("scroll-up")
        }}
        
    lastScroll = currentScroll
})
```

```css
.scroll-down header {
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0 )
}

.scroll-up header {
    filter: drop-shadow(0 -10px 20px rgb(170, 170, 170))
}
```

Above is the css classes I have added.

Comment: Please click [edit], then click the button marked `[<>]` and create a [mcve]

Comment: I have made the changes

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you want the user experience to be because while it may seem to them they are scrolling 'once' in fact the system may fire the event more than once (e.g. imagine a lengthy 'continuous' scroll).

Comment: Please add HTML so the page can actually scroll

Comment: Please make your snippet something we can run which shows us the problem. At the moment there is no HTML/nothing to scroll.

Comment: You may find this link helpful as it discusses throttling (cutting down the rate at whih scroll events are dealt with) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event The main thing to do first is decide exactly what you want the user to experience (including on different size viewports).

Comment: Do you want me to include all of my code?

Comment: No, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The problem you see is because you scoll events are fired very often. Scrolling "twice" can happen in milliseconds. What you'd prefer, I think, is to have the user scroll a certain amount up, instead of just counting.

```
const body = document.body
let lastScroll = 0;
let scrollUp_Height = 0;

window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const currentScroll = window.pageYOffset

    
    //top of the page
    if (currentScroll <= 0 ) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-up")
        scrollUp_Height = 0
    }

    // Scrolling down
    if (currentScroll > lastScroll && !body.classList.contains("scroll-down")) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-up")
        body.classList.add("scroll-down")
        scrollUp_Height = 0

    }
    // Scrolling up
    if (currentScroll < lastScroll && body.classList.contains("scroll-down")) {
        body.classList.remove("scroll-down");
    }
    if(currentScroll < lastScroll){
        // Sum the amount scrolled.
        scrollUp_Height += currentScroll - lastScroll;
        
        // If user scrolled 200 pixels up, show the bar.
        if (scrollUp_Height >= 200) {
            body.classList.add("scroll-up")
        }
     }
        
     lastScroll = currentScroll

})
```

Here I've made it so instead of counting amounts of times the event fired, I'm counting the amount of pixels scrolled up. I've put an arbitrary 200 in the code for now but you can play with this number. You could also use a calculated value to maybe act when the user scrolls 20% of its viewport or something similar if you'd like.

Comment: The problem is still occurring. I thank you for your perspective.